# General info to get started... Creating a SIP client

Tags: php, client, sip, telecommunication

I'm trying to write a PHP script which reads [SIP (session initiation protocol)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) signals from a hardware switch to gets specific details and then return some data back to the switch.

Being a complete newbie to this SIP thing I don't know how to interact with the switch sending SIP signal. Do we need to send some message to the switch to get response?
I googled SIP but got only general info regarding what SIP is all about but nothing programmatic.

Can any one provide any pointers to any tutorials which show how interact with a SIP signal programmatically?

Are there any free online services that simulate SIP signals for testing purpose?

Comment: I'm curious too. Hope someone will answer

Answer (score 0):

SIP is a protocol designed to establish and control streams of data between two or more people. (Usually this means a stream of voice data.)

It sounds like you want to ask the switch (is it a piece of hardware that handles SIP calls?) for information, perhaps on the number of calls the switch is currently handling, or similar.

I don't think you actually want to use SIP to talk to this device. I'd advise telling us what that switch is, and finding its reference manual.

Comment: ok the switch is a hardware which handles IP calls.So what it does is it sends the called number and calling number to a client program (using SIP protocol) which is the php script that i'm planning to write down.It extracts the info from the message received from switch and sends back the routing info back to  the switch.

Comment: What's the name/model of the device?

Answer (score 0):

The web domain should be noted, PHP is mainly used to create dynamic XML content, it is used in a way that tend SIP to work out to be the same to other types of scripting background, which is used to enhance the call routing and switching placement.   For more details check our website: - https://www.true-telecom.com/sip